# Create selection when I sliding my finger throught the word

Tags: android, xamarin, colors

How can I create this selections (see image bellow) when I sliding my finger throught the word, using canvas to draw a Line ou a rect.
My letters are buttons, placed in a GridLayout 15x15.
If possible, with transparent colors.
Thanks!

[Image to Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xef4x.png)

**EDIT**

I'm trying this, but nothing. View v is one letter (button)

On Method OnTouch

```
switch (e.Action) 
{ 
    case MotionEventActions.Down: 
        _X = e.GetX(); 
        _Y = e.GetY(); 
    break; 

    case MotionEventActions.Move: 
        var left = (int)(e.RawX - X); 
        var right = (int)(left + v.Width); 
        Canvas c = new Canvas(); c
        .DrawRect(new Rect(_X, _Y, _X + 200, _Y + 200), new Paint() { Color = Color.Red }); 
        ((GridLayout)v.Parent).Draw(c); 
    break; 
} 
return true;
```

Comment: try to use canvas to draw line when finger slide through word

Comment: I´m starting up and did try it, but no sucess. I need to an simple example.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please read [this guide](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) on how a question should be formulated for your increasing your chances of getting an answer you can use. As it is right now, there are too many different good answers as the question is too broad. You could narrow it down by including what you have tried yourself. This is, after all, a site for code help.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a 2d array of points and when user start touch from suppose pArr[2][2] to pArr[2][5] you can create a canvas with points of pArr[2][2] and pArr[2][5] and you can add that canvas on view.

Comment: can you send a simple example?

Comment: private void update(){
switch(event){
    case Event.Down:
var _X = e.GetX();
 var _Y = e.GetY();
// Create a global Canvas for Line draw
canvas=new Canvas();
// add canvas to view
break;
case Event.Move:
var left = getTouchX(); 
var top = getTouchY();
canvas.UpdateLine(left,right);// invalidate
// update line will only update last points something like
// canvas.drawLine(0, 0, left, top, paint);
    break; 
}

Comment: you can try something like this

Comment: Thanks, i'm trying but, the canvas does not appears. I think it is behind the buttons.

Comment: You have to add canvas on a transparent layout which will be in front(above of all views).

Comment: Thanks, I did got something with this. Maybe i will get make do i want.